# Understanding some groovy code in java

Tags: java, groovy

For some reason I need to rewrite groovy code to java. It's gradle plugin if it matters. But I don't understand some code. Could you please explain it step-by-step, probably with java code?

```
class DeployPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.with {
            apply plugin: 'org.hidetake.ssh'
            ssh.settings {
                identity = file(ssh_file)
                knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
                passphrase = ssh_passphrase
            }
    ...
```

As far as I understand `project.with{ }` means methods (which?) inside are called for `project` instance.

`apply plugin: 'org.hidetake.ssh'` - can it be expressed with `project.getPlugins() .apply("org.hidetake.ssh")` ?

`ssh.settings` - what is `ssh` here? If it is a variable, how can I get it's instance in java?

`ssh.settings {someExpressions}` - what are curly braces used for in this context?

Comment: `ssh` probably is got through `project.getSsh()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will probably look something like this in Java:

```
public class DeployPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPlugins().apply("org.hidetake.ssh");
        org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service ssh = project.getExtensions().getByType(org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service.class);
        ssh.settings(new MethodClosure(this, "configureSettingsClosure"));
    }

    private void configureSettingsClosure(org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.settings.GlobalSettings settings) {
        settings.setIdentity(ssh_file);
        settings.setKnownHosts(settings.getAllowAnyHosts());
        settings.setPassphrase("p@ssw0rd");
    }
```

or if you want to not depend on `groovy-ssh` probably something like this, but I'd not recommend it:

```
public class DeployPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPlugins().apply("org.hidetake.ssh");
        Object ssh = project.getExtensions().getByName("ssh");
        try {
            Method settings = ssh.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("settings", Closure.class);
            settings.invoke(ssh, new MethodClosure(this, "configureSettingsClosure"));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Should not happen except by using a different groovy-ssh version that changed incompatibly", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void configureSettingsClosure(Object settings) throws InvocationTargetException {
        try {
            Method setIdentity = settings.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setIdentity", Object.class);
            setIdentity.invoke(settings, ssh_file);
            Method getAllowAnyHosts = settings.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getAllowAnyHosts");
            Method setKnownHosts = settings.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setKnownHosts", File.class);
            setKnownHosts.invoke(settings, getAllowAnyHosts.invoke(settings));
            Method setPassphrase = settings.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setPassphrase", String.class);
            setPassphrase.invoke(settings, "p@ssw0rd");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Should not happen except by using a different groovy-ssh version that changed incompatibly", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly I was trying to understand if script can be properly rewritten in java code. Seems it is not very convenient. As for ssh: I decided to use JSch which is an underlying for gradle-ssh-plugin.

Comment: Well, my first version **is** the proper rewrite, I don't know what your problem is with it. And it is not really inconvenient, is it? Of course the code is a bit more verbose, but that is why Groovy is such a nice script language. You can do very condensed code.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot to understand how groovy works. Groovy is pretty itself, but in my case - long deployment script - it seems to be hard to support. Maybe it's because I've never used groovy before (neither any of my team did)

Comment: Yeah, pretty much like any language you don't know. If you know Java, then learning Groovy is relatively easy. Most syntax is very similar, but you have much additional syntactic sugar and dynamicness that you can use to write compact nicely readable code that does the same as much longer Java quivalent. :-)